# How do I vertically align google's material icon with text in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a row widget, where the warning icon is displayed next to two text sections. In  the screenshot, it looks like the alignment of the icon is at the upper level of the biggest text. I have the mainAxisAlignment and the crossAxisAlignment, and textBaseline all defined to make sure they all align at the bottom, however the icon does not seem to follow the rule. I have a screenshot and my code to also show as well.

[image: Picture of the Icon misaligned vertically]

This is how I want it to look like:

[image: My figma design for how I want it to look like]

With everything aligned at the bottom

In the screen shot you can see the warning Icon is slightly higher than the rest of the text. Here is my code (in dart):

```
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
          textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
          children: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return  const SizedBox(
                      child: WarningModal(),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.warning_amber_rounded, size: 30.0),
            ),
            Text('\$$progressAmt',
                style: const TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, fontSize: 24)),
            Text(' of $totalProgress',
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16)), 
            
          ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

Update crossAxisAlignment to `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,`

```
 Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
    textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
    children: [
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
        children: [
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return SizedBox(
                    child: Container(),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
            child: const Icon(Icons.warning_amber_rounded, size: 30.0),
          ),
          Text(
            '\$$progressAmt',
     

   style: const TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, fontSize: 24),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Text(
            ' of $totalProgress',
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

Comment: I just tried that, it did align the Icon and the text that's 24 size, however, the the text that is 16 size is center aligned as well. Thank you for the suggestion though

Comment: @Thenamesoak, I have updated the code, with some additional info. Have a look

Comment: I just tried it out and it still aligned it as if I was just doing it as: crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center. I appreciate the help though, I have a better idea on how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Update

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic
```

to

`crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center`

This should solve the issue. for you.